# NodeJS - how to break a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, return, break

Recently had a similar question, but still can't get it. I have to validate registration page before adding new user.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    //checking if first name is filled
    if (req.body.first_name = "" || req.body.first_name = null || req.body.first_name = undefined) {
      res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "error" : "empty_first_name" });
      break;
    }
    //checking if last name is filled
    if (req.body.last_name = "" || req.body.last_name = null || req.body.last_name = undefined) {
      res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "error" : "empty_last_name" });
      break;
    }
    //checking if email is filled
    if (req.body.email = "" || req.body.email = null || req.body.email = undefined) {
      res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "error" : "empty_email" });
      break;
    }
    //checking if passwords match
    if (req.body.password != req.body.repassword) {
      res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "error" : "pass_missmatch" });
      break;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //and finally if everything seems to be OK...
    addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.first_name, req.body.last_name, req.body.country, function(status) {
        res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "success" : 1 });
    });
});
```

Node.JS tells me that all the breaks are illegial. But how should I break my function in a proper way? It doesn't return anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

A `return` statement is used to halt a function.

You can provide an optional return value, but in this case, I believe it would be ignored, so you should just be able to replace `break;` with `return;`.

---

Side note, but you have a good bit of repeating code, and you have assignments in your `if` conditions. You can usually factor away the repetition. Also, you can get rid of the `return` altogether if you use `if/else if/else` statements.

Here's an example.

```
function isEmpty(val) {
    return val === "" || val == null;
}

function renderWithError(req, res, msg) {
    res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "error" : msg });
}

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    if (isEmpty(req.body.first_name)) {
      renderWithError(req, res, "empty_first_name");
    }
    else if (isEmpty(req.body.last_name)) {
      renderWithError(req, res, "empty_last_name");
    }
    else if (isEmpty(req.body.email)) {
      renderWithError(req, res, "empty_email");
    }
    else if (req.body.password != req.body.repassword) {
      renderWithError(req, res, "pass_missmatch");
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    else {
        addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.first_name, req.body.last_name, req.body.country, function(status) {
            res.render('signup', { "title": "Ttitle", "menu": "signup", user: req.user, "success" : 1 });
        });
    }
});
```

---

Comment: You mean smth like return null?

Comment: @IlyaRusanen: Just `return;` should do the trick. There's no requirement to provide an explicit return value.