# I want the code to end here.The following steps do not continue. How can I do it?

Tags: node.js

```
User.findOne({ where: { email: email } })
 .then(user => {
   if(user){
     req.session.errorMessage = 'This e-mail address has already been registered. ';
     req.session.save();
     return res.redirect('/register'); 
}
     return bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
}).then(hashedPassword =>{
            .......
        }).then(() => {
            .......   
        }).then(() => {
            .......
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

[return res.redirect('/register');] if user not exist I want the code to end here.The following steps will not continue.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think throwing an Error should stop the second .then from being triggered

Comment: Duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662930/nodejs-how-to-break-a-function

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate of that question @codeangler, return statements have unique behavior in a promise chain.

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking apart the logic & naming the functions:

```js
User.findOne({ where: { email: email } })
 .then(user => {
   if(user){
     req.session.errorMessage = 'This e-mail address has already been registered.';
     req.session.save();
     return res.redirect('/register'); 
   }
   return saveHashedUser(user, bcrypt.hash(password, 10));
})

function saveHashedUser(user, hashedPassword) {
  return hashedPassword =>{
            .......
        }).then(() => {
            .......   
        }).then(() => {
            .......
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```